# Why Getting Priority Queue using Linked List Front Element Error in C?

Tags: c, linked-list, queue

The Priority Queue is working fine the only problem is its always showing the front element as

```
id:0
priority:0
Name:(null)
```

but its arranging the next data according to its priority value. how can i get rid of this front element.
plus i am not allowed to declare any variable globally.

the code as below.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
struct PriorQueue
{
    int priority;
    char *data;
    int id;
    struct PriorQueue *next;

};
void AddPatient(struct PriorQueue *p,char name[],int pr);
void TreatPatient(struct PriorQueue *p);
void DisplayFirstPatient(struct PriorQueue *p);
void DisplayAll(struct PriorQueue *p);
struct PriorQueue *newnode(struct PriorQueue *p,int pr,char data[]);
int isEmpty(struct PriorQueue *p);
```

The main method:

```
int main(void)
{
    struct PriorQueue p={NULL};
    char name[10];
    int ch=0;
    int pr=0;

    do
    {
        printf("\n\tMENU");
        printf("\n\t 1.Add Patient");
        printf("\n\t 2.Treat a Patient");
        printf("\n\t 3.Display First Patient");
        printf("\n\t 4.Display all Patient");
        printf("\n\t 0.Exit");
        printf("\n\tEnter your choice:");
        scanf("%d",&ch);
        switch(ch)
        {
        case 1://INSERT
            printf("\n\tEnter Name:");
            scanf("%s",&name);
            printf("\n\t Enter Priority:");
            scanf("%d",&pr);

                AddPatient(&p,name,pr);


            break;

        case 2:
              TreatPatient(&p);
              break;

        case 3://DISPLAY FRONT
            DisplayFirstPatient(&p);


            break;

        case 4://DISPLAY ALL
            printf("\n\tQueue Elements");
            DisplayAll(&p);
            break;

        case 5:
            printf("\n\tThank you!");
        default:
            printf("\n\tInvalid choice");
        }
    }while(ch!=0);
    return 0; }
```

Rest of the functions:

```
void AddPatient(struct PriorQueue *p,char name[],int pr)
{
    struct PriorQueue *start;
    struct PriorQueue *front=NULL;
    struct PriorQueue *temp=(struct PriorQueue *)calloc(1,sizeof(struct PriorQueue));
    temp->data=strdup(name);
    temp->priority=pr;
    temp->id=p->id+1;
    front=p;

     if(front==NULL || front->priority > pr)
    {
        temp->next=front;
        front=temp;
    }
    else
    {   start=p;
        while(start->next!=NULL && start->next->priority <= pr)
        {
            start=start->next;
        }
        temp->next=start->next;
        start->next=temp;
    }
    p=front;


}
int isEmpty(struct PriorQueue *p)
{

    return p==NULL;
}
void DisplayFirstPatient(struct PriorQueue *p)
{
    printf("\n\t First Patient Details:");
    printf("\n\t id:%d",p->id);
    printf("\n\t priority:%d",p->priority);
    printf("\n\t Name:%s",p->data);

}
void DisplayAll(struct PriorQueue *p)
{
    struct PriorQueue *temp=p;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("\n\t id:%d",temp->id);
        printf("\n\t priority:%d",temp->priority);
        printf("\n\t Name:%s",temp->data);
        temp=temp->next;
    }


}

void TreatPatient(struct PriorQueue *p)
{
    struct PriorQueue *temp=p;
    p=p->next;
    free(temp);
}
```

Comment: The first element of your queue is `p`, which you have explicitly initialized to all zeros / nulls. That element is always there, even if you haven't added any patients and that's what you see when you print. Your queue has a fixed element instead of a head. Make `p` a pointer to a node, which starts as `NULL`. Then find a way to update that pointer from `AddPatient` in case you have to change it, because you add a node at the front.

Comment: @MOehm should i make AddPatient function struct type and return node and store it in p?

Comment: Yes, that's one possibility. Alternatively, you can pass a pointer to a pointer to your node struct, `struct PriorQueue **p` and then, at the end, set `*p = front`. (What you are doing now is to change the local variable `p`, which will have no effect in `main`.)

Comment: yes , this double pointer works thanks a lot :) @MOehm